# How to get arc length of a function?

Tags: math, cas, maxima

I want to get the arclength of a parametric function. For t -5..5.How can I get this ? And how can I set the nticks right here in the function to get more precise results? Something with Phytagoras?

```
 f(t):= t^2 -4*t:
 g(t):= t12 -2*t +3;
```

Comment: Arc length is a property of a curve, not a function. (For example, if F is a function that assigns to each student his or her favourite subject, there is no natural concept of 'arc length'.)

Answer (score 1):

[It is known](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/math214-2-04f/notes/c2-arclength.pdf) that arc length of parametric curve is

```
L=Integral[t=a..b](ds)
```

where

```
ds = Sqrt(f'(t)^2 +g'(t)^2)dt
```

here

```
ds = Sqrt((2t-4)^2+(2t-2)^2)dt = 
     Sqrt(4t^2-16t+16+4t^2-8t+4)dt=
     2*Sqrt(2t^2-6t+5)dt
```

To get integral, you can use [wolframalpha service](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral%28Sqrt%282t%5E2-6t%2B5%29dt).
It is possible to calculate value of this integral in limits (79.5), but I suspect that general formula is more useful.